# sending data using ajax to laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to send a multi step form data separately to the Laravel controller to store them into MySQL.
For example send below inputs data !

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" class="step1r1" value="1" name="step1">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" class="step1r2" value="2" name="step1">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" class="step1r3" value="3" name="step1">

    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" class="step1r4" value="" name="step1">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: and what have you tried to do this? you are only showing some HTML

Answer (score 0):

Something like this i suppose if i understand you correctly.

```
   $(".step1r1").onChange(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/post-route",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: $(".step1r1").val(),
        success: function(data){
         // success 
         }
        }
      });
    });
```